# Quantum ESPRESSO ph.x output

Tags: quantum-espresso, phonons, symmetry, kohn-sham

I wanted to calculate the normal modes of some particular material using the Quantum ESPRESSO. Everything went fairly well, but there is a couple of lines in the output that I do not understand. In particular, one of the lines that came out in the ph.out file reads as:

```
freq ( 4 - 5) = 62.3 [cm-1] --> E_u X_5' M_5' I
```

From here we can read off the phonon frequency $\left(62.3 \,\textrm{cm}^{-1}\right)$ and we can also see that this particular vibration belongs to $E_u$ irreducible representations. It is also possible to see that this mode is IR active. However, I do not understand this piece of information:

```
X_5' M_5'
```

What does this tell us?

PS: We are working with point group  $D_{4h}$ ([4/mmm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragonal_crystal_system)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For questions like these where the answer is not provided by the Quantum ESPRESSO user guide, it usually pays off to search the source code on the [QE gitlab repository](https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e).

Searching for "freq" turns up [find_mode_sym.f90](https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e/-/blob/develop/PHonon/PH/find_mode_sym.f90#L360), which shows that this information is stored in the `name_rap` variable.
Searching for "name_rap(1)" turns up [PW/src/divide_class.f90](https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e/-/blob/develop/PW/src/divide_class.f90#L2104-2115)

The comment documenting the `set_irr_rap` subroutine mentions

> Various names have been used in the litterature to identify
> the irreducible representations. Several equivalent names are
> collected in this routine. The first name is taken
> from the book of P.W. Atkins, M.S. Child, and C.S.G. Phillips,
> "Tables for group theory".
> D, G, L, S are used for Delta, Gamma, Lambda and Sigma.
> Representations which correspond to infrared or raman active modes
> are identified with the string in ir_ram: I (infrared active),
> R (Raman active), I+R (Infrared and Raman active).

I.e. `X_5'` and `M_5'` are just labels for the `E_u` representation in alternative labelling schemes [1].

[1] Which labelling schemes I don't know but I'm also not an expert in point groups.
Clicking on `blame` will tell you that the last person who touched this code is Andrea dal Corso in 2006.
If you would like to contribute to improving the documentation, I suggest you [open an issue](https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e/-/issues) and ping @dalcorso for a reference concerning these symbols.